# missing 'content-length' header when using python's urllib2 urlopen

Tags: python, urllib2

When attempting to check the 'content-length' header for some web pages using urllib2 in python, the header is missing.  For example, the response from google.com is missing this header.  Any idea why?

Example:

```
r = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
i = r.info()
print i.keys()
```

Gives:

```
['x-xss-protection', 'set-cookie', 'expires', 'server', 'connection', 'cache-control', 'date', 'p3p', 'content-type', 'x-frame-options']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) that an http response can either contain `Content-Length` or `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

However, when `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is used in the header, after the headers, you'll get a hexadecimal string which if converted to decimal, will give you the length of the next chunk. And after the last chunk you'll get a `0` for this value which means you've reached the end of the file.

You can use regular expressions to get this hexadecimal value (not a must though)

```
read = #string containing a line or a part of the http response
hexPat = re.compile(r'([0-9A-F]+)\r\n', re.I)
match = re.search(hexPat, read)
chunkLen = int(match.group(1), 16) #converts hexadecimal to decimal
```

or You can just read the first hexadecimal value, get the length of the first chunk and receive that chunk, then get the length of the next chunk and so on till you find a `0`

Comment: Thanks for the info on transfer-encoding.  Do you know how to get the string for 'read' in your code snippet via urllib2?  If I try r.read() in my example above, I get the full html code for google.com and no hexadecimal prefix telling me the chunk size or anything.  Is urllib2 too high level to examine the response one chunk at a time?

Comment: @user1369195 I'm not sure, but I think it is too high level.
When I used that, I was working on a low level using sockets.

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Length of a HEAD response SHOULD, but not always does include the Content-Length value of a GET response:

Stack Overflow does:

```
> telnet stackoverflow.com 80
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
Content-Length: 362245                           <--------
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 04 Oct 2010 11:51:49 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 04 Oct 2010 11:50:49 GMT
Vary: *
Date: Mon, 04 Oct 2010 11:50:49 GMT
```

Google doesn't:

```
> telnet www.google.com 80
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.ie


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 04 Oct 2010 11:55:36 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Comment: Do you know of any way to check the size of a page before downloading the whole thing when the 'content-length' header is missing?